# 2-Dimensional char array gets filled with wrong input in C

Tags: c, arrays

I programm a Whatsapp chat analyser. It is written in C. First, a exportet  Whatsapp-chat gets opened by my programme with fopen();...Later it should save the names of the members of the Chat in a temporary array, then they should be written(if the same name isn`t already in the end_array) in the end_array. Else, the the line will be skipped.

**Detection of the names of the members:**

The chars between - 'my name' : gets saved

07.11.17, 14:38 - Alan (TFO): Alan

**The problem:** End_Array gets filled with strange chars (Seee Image below) How can I solve this? In the first line should only be 'andisville', in the second line Florian Steger ....

[image: Problem:]

**Names:**
[image: Chat txt]

**Code:**

```
#include <stdio.h>
#include <stdlib.h>
#include <string.h>

int printEndArr(int nl, int members, char end_arr3[nl][members]);
int clearArray(int nl, int members, char end_arr3[nl][members]);

int main()
{
   FILE *fp;
   fp = fopen("datei3.txt", "r");

   int a = 0;
   int i = 0; 
   int k = 0; 
   int c = 0; 
   int c2 = -1; 
   int j = 0;
   int members = 0; 
   int m; 
   int n,strc  = 0;
   int x,z, zus = 1, nl = 30,zl =0,zle =0,zlex = 0,firc;    
   //Don't ask me why I formatted the declarations so bad

   char chr, *statBeff; 

   scanf("%d",&members);
   char end_arr3[nl][members];
   char temp_array[nl];
   int counter[members];

   clearArray(nl,members, end_arr3);

   if(fp == NULL)
   {
      printf("Achtung die Datei existiert nicht!");//The File doesn`t exist
   }
   else
   {
      for(i = 0; chr != EOF; i++)       //Read every char of the text file
      { 
         chr = fgetc(fp);
         if(chr == '-')
         {
            chr = fgetc(fp);
            if(chr == ' ')
            {
               j=0;
               while((chr = fgetc(fp))!=':')
               {
                  temp_array[j] = chr;
                  j++;
               }

               temp_array[j] = '\0'; //The tempArray gets terminated by '\0'

               if((strstr(temp_array, "Betreff") == NULL)) //If the temporary array doesn't contain the String 'Betreff'..
               {
                  for(z=0; z < members;z++)
                  {
                     if(strcmp(end_arr3[z],temp_array)==0) //Prove if the name of the temp_array is already in the endarray
                     {
                        strc = 1;
                        a--;                
                        break;
                     }  
                  }
                  if (strc == 0)//If the temparray isn't in the end array:
                  {
                     strcpy(end_arr3[a], temp_array);
                  }
               }
               else
               {
                  a--;
               }

               strc =0;
               ++a;
               if(a == members) //If all members of the whatsapp chat are found the for-loop will be determinated
               break;
            }
         }
      }       
   }       
   printEndArr(nl,members, end_arr3); //end array gets printed

   fclose(fp);

   return 0;
}

int printEndArr(int nl, int members, char end_arr3[nl][members])
{
   int i,k;

   for(i=0;i<members;i++)
   {
      for(k=0;k<nl;k++)
      {
         printf("%c",end_arr3[i][k]);
      }
      printf("\n");
   }

   return 0;
}


int clearArray(int nl, int members, char end_arr3[nl][members])
{
   int i,k;

   for(i=0;i<members;i++)
   {
      for(k=0;k<nl;k++)
      {
         end_arr3[i][k] = ' ';
      }
   }

   return 0;
}
```

Comment: haven't you posted the same question recently? https://stackoverflow.com/questions/48595813/c-programm-array-doesnt-fill-correctly

Comment: I deleted the thread, I opened a new one.

Comment: Unrelated to your problem, but [`fgetc`](http://en.cppreference.com/w/c/io/fgetc) returns an `int`. This is actually important when you check for `EOF`.

Comment: that's not really the way SO works. You should edit your old question instead. Posting the same question over and over will get you banned after a while. Be careful with that. Also, your question is off-topic: posting as much code and expecting others to debug it for you isn't very nice. a [mcve] is much better.

Comment: `chr != EOF` is wrong: you test for EOF after the fact. You must test `if ((chr = fgetc(fp)) != EOF)`

Comment: Yea, there should only be a little problem, but I can't see it

Comment: It also seems that you should spend some time to [learn how to debug your programs](https://ericlippert.com/2014/03/05/how-to-debug-small-programs/).

Comment: @PaulOgilvie isn't it the same...?

Comment: @Someprogrammerdude you are rght..

Comment: Treating the strings as arrays of spaces looks very odd. When printing with `printf("%c",end_arr3[i][k]);` you print a whole lot of trailing spaces. Why not treat it as strings, with a terminating null character?

Comment: That would be good, but how can I set up that the string gets terminated after the last char of the name in the end_array?

Comment: No, it is not the same because you first get `chr` (that happens to be EOF) and _you process that char_ in your `else` part and beyond, and only then will the `for`condition be tested again to conclude EOF.

Comment: I will test this now

Comment: After doing this, the array is completely blank

Comment: Does your input contain '\n' newline characters to show the beginning of another record?  If so, I may consider a `fgets()` approach as this will give you some nice strings to work with instead of the char fun you have now.

Comment: I have the impression that everyone here is feeding the help vampire.

Answer (score 1):

You've declared `end_arr3` backwards:

```
char end_arr3[nl][members];
```

where `nl` is the *length* of the space for each string and `members` is the *number* of strings.  But this sets aside space for `nl` strings each of length `members`.

Comment: Ok I have done that, now the first line is correct, the rest of the lines is like before